# React-admin pagination count number is not correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-admin

I have found solution for pagination to take N elements per page
BUT the i don't found solution or documentation to get count number  of pages.
[image]

is incorrect ,
PLS help

Comment: You'll have to expand on this, how is the pagination count number incorrect? Based on the image everything looks fine (63 pages for 315 results at 5/page and page 10 would be 46-50). Also you should share your code.

Comment: @HenryWoody i don't have 315 i have 10 and when click on page 3 return to page 1 cause there is no data left.

Comment: That's what I mean, you need to include your code and explain the problem because the picture looks fine (since that's all the information we have)

Answer (score 2):

It is probable that your `dataProvider.getList()` doesn't return the correct `total`. The expected response format should be:

`{ data: record[], total: number }`

Where `total` is the total number excluding pagination (i.e. if you have a pagination of 10, but the query has 150 results, `total` should be 150 on every page).

See https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviderWriting.html#example-rest-implementation for more information.

Comment: i have fix it by add 
res.setHeader('content-range', await (await TABLE.findMany({})).length);
thanks a lot